# Como establecer opacidad para una imagen pero no para el texto en un recyclerView (android)

Tags: android-studio

tengo un recyclerView al cual le paso imagenes y texto, en el activity que alimenta al recyclerView estoy tratando de establecer opacidad para las imagenes pero no para el texto, sin embargo se afectan ambos y no es lo que quiero. Como logro que no se afecte el texto al establecerle la opacidad a la imagen?`

Activity que alimenta el recyclerView (en el que quiero establecer la opacidad solo a la imagen)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImagen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/beers"
        android:alpha="0.5"/>


</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Nombre"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

`

Activity del recyclerView

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido, dices que si cambias android:alpha de la imageview (idImagen) tambien se cambia del texview (idNombre) que no se encuentra ni en el mismo linearlayout? Adjunta el código donde cambias programáticamente la opacidad

Comment: Exactamente!!, Se me pone el TextView opaco tambien, incluso sin estar dentro del linear layout, antes lo tenia dentro del linearlayout y lo he sacado a ver si asi funcionaba pero no, se sigue poniendo opaco el texto, si quieres te comparto los codigos del adaptador para el recyclerview

Comment: Sería conveniente que compartieras el código del adaptador si. A simple vista no tiene sentido que suceda lo que dices a menos que cambies el alpha en algún otro sitio u otro componente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de las siguientes formas:

1. Es crear un xml de tipo bitmap con la imagen que quiera poner de fondo y aplicarle a esta la propiedad `android:alpha`, de este modo no afectaras la opacidad de elementos secundarios. Entonces en `res/drawable`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:src="@drawable/tuImagen"
       android:alpha="0.4"/>
   ```
2. En caso de que la opacidad la quieras aplicar pragmáticamente, desde java puedes hacer lo siguiente:

   ```
   yourView.getBackground().setAlpha(120);
   ```

Ojala te sirvan las herramientas.

Answer (score 0):

**LO MÁS FÁCIL:**

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/skyline_favoritos"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black" 
        android:alpha="0.2"/>  <!-- 1 opaco - 0 transparente -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

De esta forma oscureces la imagen principal del color que quieras y con la opacidas que busques